# How do I encrypt fields using keys stored in web.config using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, encryption, cryptography

I am hoping that someone will be able to help me out with my issue. I have been tasked with writing a program that will be used by our HR department. This program will be a subset of the intranet and will further be limited based on the user's department. This program will contain an employee profile which will store some sensitive information such as Social Security Numbers. I am trying to find the best way to encrypt the SSNs so that they are not readable as plain text in the database.

I have found code that works which uses some built-in functions of VB.NET using the System.Security.Cryptography namespace as stated [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/67705-rsa-encryption-in-vbnet/).

The code works as when the data is inserted into the database the field is encrypted. The problem I face with this is that when I want to pull the employee back up, I am unable to decrypt it. My guess is because I do this on the page that I need the value decrypted:

```
Dim rsa As New RSACryptoServiceProvider
```

Which would basically define a new crypto service provider instead of the one that I used to encrypt the data in the first place. I am wondering if when you do New RSACryptoServiceProvider it comes up with a new public/private key pair?

My next thought was to see about storing the encryption and decryption keys in the web.config so that no matter what page the user is on the data can be decrypted. I have not found a good example of using this as everything I see shows how to encrypt/decrypt fields in the web.config (such as passwords and connections to the database), not actually use it in the application. Would this be a good way to go about encrypting the data? As stated this will be a subset of the intranet so the application will be held locally with no exposure to the outside. I am just very uncomfortable with having SSNs readable in the database.

This is my first foray into encryption so I apologize if this is a simple question.

I am using VB.NET in Visual Studio 2015 connected to SQL SERVER 2008 R2. I am open to any suggestions that anyone has.

Comment: Why do you need SSN for a profile that controls intranet access?  It seems like that information would not be needed at all.  I know I wouldn't want to give my SSN for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you for responding. The SSN has nothing to do with profile that controls the intranet access. The SSN would be used in an employee profile that only HR would use. Only HR would be able to get to this page based on Active Directory permissions. I need the SSNs in the employee profile because the thought is that if HR needed to, they could recreate everything about the employee. The SSN would live in an employee database with that field being encrypted. Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to do what I am looking for. While Alex's solution works, having the encryption done within the VB.NET code offers the ability to pass in different keys so that different sections of data can be encrypted differently. Essentially if someone happens to get one of the keys, they will only have some of the data, not all of it. This is not a perfect solution, but it is better than having fields display as plaintext in the the database.

I created a class file and put it in the App_Code folder and called it Simple3Des. The class looks like this:

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class Simple3Des

    Private TripleDes As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider

    Private Shared Function TruncateHash(ByVal key As String, ByVal length As Integer) As Byte()
        Dim sha1 As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
        //hash the key
        Dim keyBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key)
        Dim hash() As Byte = sha1.ComputeHash(keyBytes)
        //truncate or pad the hash
        ReDim Preserve hash(length - 1)
        Return hash
    End Function

    Public Shared Function EncryptData(ByVal plaintext As String, ByVal key As String) As String
        //convert the plaintext string to a byte array
        Dim threeDes As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
        threeDes.Key = TruncateHash(key, threeDes.KeySize \ 8)
        threeDes.IV = TruncateHash("", threeDes.BlockSize \ 8)
        Dim plaintextBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plaintext)
        //create the stream
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        //create the encoder to write the byte array to the stream
        Dim encStream As New CryptoStream(ms, threeDes.CreateEncryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        encStream.Write(plaintextBytes, 0, plaintextBytes.Length)
        encStream.FlushFinalBlock()
        //convert the encrypted stream to a printable string
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray)
    End Function

    Public Shared Function DecryptData(ByVal encryptedtext As String, ByVal key As String) As String
        //convert the encrypted text string to a byte array
        Dim threeDes As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
        threeDes.Key = TruncateHash(key, threeDes.KeySize \ 8)
        threeDes.IV = TruncateHash("", threeDes.BlockSize \ 8)
        Dim encryptedBytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedtext)
        //create the stream
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        //create the decoder to write to the stream
        Dim decStream As New CryptoStream(ms, threedes.CreateDecryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        //use the crypt stream to write the byte array to the stream
        decStream.Write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length)
        decStream.FlushFinalBlock()
        //convert the plaintext stream to a string
        Return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray)
    End Function

End Class
```

Then use the below to call the class:

```
//to encrypt
Simple3Des.EncryptData("Data to encrypt", "key")
//to decrypt
Simple3Des.DecryptData("Data to decrypt", "key")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that encrypted data is only as protected as encryption keys. Storing encryption keys in web.config or any other file, while convenient, is not terribly secure.

One way of doing what you want using database only tools is:

To encrypt the SSN column using database keys, this allows you to control who has access to keys and therefore who can decrypt data.
You can optionally create a View that will attempt to decrypt data, or return NULL if user has no access to decryption keys.

I would advise creating keys using `KEY_SOURCE` string so that you can re-create them in case of a disaster and also to backup database master key, failing to do this and as well as not doing a recovery test could leave you with irrecoverably lost data.

Further details are in this great article:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3081/using-views-to-expose-encrypted-data-in-sql-server/.

Comment: Thank you, I think that this could work. I'm not sure if I'm missing something though, where would the encryption/decryption password come from? Is it something that I would pass into the view as a parameter from my vb.net application? Otherwise if they are in the view wouldn't anyone with access to the database be able to see the passwords and have access to that information?

Comment: There is no need for decryption password as decryption authorisation is handled by user permissions in SQL Server i.e. in very simplified terms: a user A connects to the database, database checks if user A has permission to use decryption key, if yes user A can see data, if not then NULLs are returned

Comment: I suggest you read up on [SQL Server encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/sql-server-encryption) first before you start doing any changes. I also strongly recommend that you follow one of the existing approaches as opposed to inventing your own. It is too easy to make a small omission in design/implementation that would greatly compromise overall security.